# String resource with index letter

Tags: android

I have not found it anywhere so I am asking.
How can I write string with upper index? Prefferably in resources.
For example I want write square meters as m2 where 2 is upper index.

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If it is only for ² and ³: Those are available at UTF 00B2 resp. 00B3 so you can just use the entity notation: `The area is 2 m\u00B2.`. Or use the character directly, if your keyboard supports it or copy and paste it into the file.

Comment: yeah perfect, looks like superscript but can't we have more character?

Comment: +1 I also used the same for TM ......@hotveryspicy "can't we have more character" ? not get ?

Comment: Thanks it works nice. index is smaller than with <sup>3</sup>

Comment: @DheereshSingh more character in the sense, this is working only for 2,3 but what about tm, copyright and etc?

Comment: You only need to check if they can be displayed by the font that is used for display.

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
M<sup>2</sup>
```

or you can use `textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("M<sup>2</sup>"));`

**Edited:**

This is my string.xml

```
<string name="hello">Hello World<sup>2</sup></string>
```

Comment: I Disagree, because superscript size is smaller than normal text and in your case it is not happening.

Comment: @hotveryspicy he wants Superscript not subscript sir

Comment: @gtumca-MAC still you can check the output of yours.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in file string:

```
<string name="acreage">Acreage (m<sup><small>2</small></sup>)</string>
```